# Pygame, get key object from character

Tags: python, pygame, key-bindings

I'm making a multiplayer platformer/shooter/brawl game with pygame and I'd like for the players to easily change their keybinds (such as from a config file).

I haven't been able to find a way to read a character string and use that as a transition to the `pygame.K_xx` objects as of now so I ask the community.

Any leads ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the constants of [this list](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) you can use

```
getattr(pygame, 'K_'+ mychar)
```

to access a constant by name.