# When writing pygame.keys[0] it does not take the value of keys[0]

Tags: python, pygame

The code works if you write pygame.K_UP, or whatever key you want, being K_UP a constant of pygame.

However, I need to write a function which takes the key as an input. For example:

```
def player(keys)
""" keys is a list """    
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keystate[pygame.keys[0]]:
        etc
```

It gives me the following error: "AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'keys' "

The objective of this is to create multiple instances of players with diferent controls, so controls are stored in a list:

```
keys = [["LEFT", "UP", "RIGHT"], ["a", "w", "d"], ["4", "8", "6"]]
keys = [["pygame.K_" + e for e in elem] for elem in keys]  # join pygame.K_ to each element

players = list()
for i in range(num_players):
    players.append(Player(keys[i]))
```

SOLUTION:
Finally, the comment of jasonharper has led me to the solution. Looking for getattr(pygame, key) I found this page with the same question: [Pygame, get key object from character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714719/pygame-get-key-object-from-character)

```
keys = [["LEFT", "UP", "RIGHT"], ["a", "w", "d"], ["4", "8", "6"]]
keys = [[getattr(pygame, "K_" + e) for e in elem] for elem in keys]
```

This solved it for me. Many thanks to all.

Comment: Why are you expecting `pygame.keys` to be a thing? What were you expecting `pygame.keys` to be?

Comment: I need keystate[pygame.K_UP] to work so that it reacts when I press UP. Keys is the name of my list.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `getattr(pygame, key)` (where `key` is a string like "K_UP".  But that's a bizarre way of doing things, introducing an additional layer of indirection for no apparent reason.  Pass `pygame.K_UP` as the parameter to the function, and you can use it directly.

Comment: Please edit the question and explain more thoroughly what you're trying to achieve. What are you passing as the `keys` argument to the `function` and why?

Comment: You could just add the key constants to the list `keys = [[pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_RIGHT], [pygame.K_a, pygame.K_w, pygame.K_d], ...` etc.. I'd also like to see your `Player` class and the whole event handling code. Please read the [mcve page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The error said everything: the pygame module does not have the keys attribute. The `keys` variable is being created by you as an argument of the function. The dot notation is used to access attributes on some object. However, in this case, you wanted to access the `keys` argument of your function.

Also, you need to understand that K_UP is the identifier of an int variable that holds some value. You are trying to access a variable by the value it holds instead of using its identifier.

```
>>> print(pygame.K_UP)
273
>>> type(pygame.K_UP)
<class 'int'>
```

Following is an example of how you can get rid of your error. By no means I am saying that this will work, since I do not have experience with Pygame, but it just shows you how you could get rid of the error.

```
>>> def function(keys):
...     keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
...     if keystate[keys[0]]:
...         pass
... 
>>> function([pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN])
>>>
```

Comment: That did not work. Though type(pygame.K_UP) is int, for some reason type(keys[0]) is str, and prints out pygame.K_UP instead of 273.

Comment: It seems that you are missing the basics of programming: it was you who defined the keys variable as a list of strings in your program, which is completely unnecessary. As I said, pygame keys are ints and you can look at the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) for further details. In fact, I just took a look at it and it already has constants for letters and the key pad you are trying to use. You are adding an extra layer above something that is already done for you. You could just use pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w and pygame.K_KP8 for moving upwards, for example.